# open new tab only after click popup ok jquery

Tags: jquery

How to create a script for open a tag href url in new window or tab only after clicking ok button in popup. there are multiple a tags with different urls.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("[target=_blank]").click(function() {
    $(".popup").toggle();
  });
  $(".cancel").click(function() {
    $(".popup").hide();
  });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/xdfoydy8/4/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it in following way:

http://jsfiddle.net/xdfoydy8/5/

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("[target=_blank]").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(".popup").show();
    $("a.ok").data("hrefData", $(this).attr("href"));
  });
  $(".cancel").click(function() {
    $(".popup").hide();
  });

  $("a.ok").click(function() {
    var href = $(this).data("hrefData");
    if ($.trim(href).length > 0) {
      window.open(href, "_blank");
    }
  });
});
```

We are setting the clicked `href` in ok link's `$.data()` and retrieving it on click of ok click and taking user to clicked `href`

Answer (score 3):

Actually, you don't need your jQuery bit to do that, all you have to do is use the JS `confirm()` function in the `onclick` event of each of your links, as such :

```
<a target="_blank" class="intro" href="http://google.com" onclick="return confirm('Popup ?');">to new Window</a><br>
<a target="_blank" class="intro" href="http://yahoo.com" onclick="return confirm('Popup ?');">to new Window</a><br>
<a class="intro" href="#" onclick="return confirm('Popup ?');">same window</a>
```

Fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/z57cnnd7/

Comment: This works, but doesn't allow the user to make a custom pop-up box. Still ++ for the solution.

Comment: The only customizable thing is the popup message (in my example, "Popup ?"), the "OK" and "cancel" buttons cannot indeed be edited (as well as the popup style, of course).

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to intercept the initial event with `e.preventDefault` and have it re-routed through the confirm pop-up modal.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("[target=_blank]").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault(); // stops the redirecting
        openToggle(e) // pass the initial even to a new function
    });
});

function openToggle(target) {
    $(".popup").toggle();

    $('.ok').click(function() {
        window.location = target.currentTarget.href;
    });

    $(".cancel").click(function() {
        $(".popup").hide();
    });
};
```

Haven't tested this yet, i'll update if neccesary

Answer (score 0):

many ways to do this - but one way is to do it like this

```
    $("[target=_blank]").click(function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      var link = $(this).attr('href');
      $(".popup").toggle();
      $('.ok').attr('href',link);
      $('.ok').attr('target',"_blank");
    });
```

This will kust make your "ok" link into the link that you originally clicked. remember to change the reversal as well.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use e.preventDefault() to stop default behavior of anchor tag.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(".links a[target=_blank]").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(".popup .ok").attr("href",$(this).attr("href"));
        $(".popup").toggle();
    });
$(".cancel,.ok").click(function(){
        $(".popup").hide();
    });
});
```

Here is fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/etqzyyob/1/

Comment: on click event of "ok", page opening in new window but popup not hiding :(

Comment: add this 
$(".cancel,.ok").click(function(){
        $(".popup").hide();
    });
});